# Bootstrap tour after another step

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am stuck here. I am using Bootstrap tour to create a walk through but not getting the desired results. Here is the problem:

I want the tour to start.
(step 1: click Hello to continue). 
The tour now pauses. 
User clicks "Hello" and another div appears. 
Then the tour should resume from step 2.

If the div is visible by default, the tour works fine. But if the div display gets enabled in another step, the tour does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tour;
  $("#get").click(function() {

    $("#get1").css('display', 'block');


  });


  $("#hello").click(function() {

    tour = new Tour({
      steps: [{
          element: "#get",
          title: "Step 1",
          content: "Click Hello to continue!"
        },
        {
          element: "#get1",
          title: "Step 2",
          content: "Great!"
        }
      ],
      storage: false
    });

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();


  });



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sam</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="hello" class="btn">Test</button>
  <div id="get" style="width: 50px">Hello</div>
  <div id="get1" style="background-color: tomato; display: none; width: 50px">test</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Sam.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8dfcvo1u/3/
(i dont think tour works on fiddle though :(

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen. Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/matthewblewitt/pen/GGyeEe Could explain what behaviour you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the codepen. I want that when the red box shows, then the second step should resume. Currently it is not working.